# Is it possible to get back to pure math graduate study after working for two years?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, mathematics, canada

I graduated with a honors computer science bachelor degree back in 2020 in Canada. During my last two years in the undergraduate study, I developed a strong interest in pure math especially algebra related courses. So I decided to continue with an after degree program (like a second degree) in Honors mathmatics.

However, I didn't do well in the pandemic and only got a C+ in the functional analysis course, which discouraged me somehow. Also, there were some personal financial issue at that time, so I decided to graduate in 2021 with only a Specialization degree in math (because I didn't complete all required courses for honors degree, but enough for specialization).

After finishing my undergraduate study, I worked as a programmer since then and was able to save some money. I don't hate my job but I never felt fulfilled writing code. In my spare time, I would do some self-study with textbooks, but I always want to study full time again. But now I am not sure how I should continue, so I was wondering if someone could give me any advice. Thanks a lot!

**TLDR:** graduated in 2021 in cs and math, work as a programmer since then, now want to get back to university to study more math but don't know how to continue

For my undergraduate study in math, I got a 3.2 GPA, and had taken all required courses in a math degree. I also had a paper published in CDC conference, it is related to game theory, I don't know if it would help my application or not. I don't know if it would be too unrealistic, but my final goal would be entering a top university  for PhD in pure math in the future. So here are some of my questions:

1. Should I apply for Master degree program or some non-degree program first to boost my GPA?
2. If I am gonna apply for Master degree program, should I apply for Non-thesis or thesis based program if my final goal is PhD study?
3. Any general suggestions or comments for my current situation?

Thank you so much for reading my messy words! I appreciate any advice or comments

Comment: Where is this? What country?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I am in Canada. I will update the description now.